# Bullet particles not colliding with cell fractured model

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I have a particle system emitting a bullet object with collision and rigid body. I have it so the particles collide with a cell fractured object which also has collision and rigid body. I have tried increasing mass of emitted object but it won't work. How can I get this to work?